# My hard drive is just randomly vanishing?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, powershell

My second drive is just randomly vanishing. It's a SSD. I can be in console on the drive and all of sudden I get:

> Set-Location : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'F' does not
>   exist. At line:1 char:13
>   + Set-Location <<<<  F:
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (F:String) [Set-Location], DriveNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand

I can shut down and power up and its back and working... Some time passes and it drops again.

Disk manager doesn't recognize it either. Windows 7.

Any ideas? Thanks.

**Event Viewer:**

> The driver detected a controller error on \Device\Harddisk3\DR3.

What driver is this?

Comment: Its likely a very basic device driver.  This isn't something that can be fixed.

Comment: @Ramhound How did it corrupt? Been working fine for over a year.... No updates recently... planned obsolescence?

Comment: I am unable to tell based on the information provided the reason the controller failed if that indeed happen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to correct my problem by updating the firmware on my SSD. Turns out it is known issue with Crucial M4 SSD to appear and disappear after 5000 hours of use. See this answer which helped:

[SATA drive disappears every hour, back on hard reboot](https://superuser.com/questions/464134/sata-drive-disappears-every-hour-back-on-hard-reboot)

**Solution:**

1. Download the latest firmware from crucial: http://www.crucial.com/support/firmware.aspx
2. Reboot PC and **set all SATA drives to IDE mode** or else the firmware upgrade will not detect the drive.
3. Update firmware and reboot and everything is working perfectly again.

*Thanks to everyone who offered suggestions.*

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if your SSD is breaking down, or that you have a broken cable in your computer.

- Did you open your computer recently, and do something with the disk?
- How old is the computer?
- Does your BIOS give (or gave) errors during booting?

You can try an application like SSD health from http://ssdhealth.com/ to see the health status of your SSD. This will only take a moment, and gives you a good idea of how far gone your disk is. If your disk randomly disappears, this is usually the result of a disk having more then 50% errors on the disk.

Finally, you could try a chkdsk to check for broken files and such, which does not per se help with the disappearing, but it could reduce the number of errors, so the disk stays connected longer.

```
chkdsk F: /F /V /R /X /B /sdcleanup /offlinescananddisk
```

This might even be a problem on your motherboard. Try connecting the SSD to a different slot on your motherboard.

Comment: Added a new video card last month. Everything has still been working properly. Will try your suggestions. Complete is around 1.5 years old. i7 Gigabyte, 24gigs ram, 3 hd, 1 sdd primary, 1 ssd backup (failing), 1 1tb storage drive. Recently downloaded ansicon, wondering if that is the culprit. See some errors in event viewer too.

Comment: `chkdsk F: /F /V /R /X /B /sdcleanup /offlinescananddisk` invalid parameter?  ----------> C:\Windows\system32>chkdsk f:
Cannot open volume for direct access.

Comment: What motherboard and BIOS version do you have? Besides plugging it in into another port, you could also try booting Windows in safe mode. If it also fails in safe mode, try starting the BIOS or the Windows recovery command line. Do some read actions on the disk and see if it happens again then.